# Filter a view by the URL

Tags: views, uri, 7

I’ve a page, called Jobpage, where I’m listing all my members within a specific content type. Then I’ve at the right sidebar a list of geographical locations which each member has entered when signing up. I want my users to filter the Jobpage but instead of getting all the members for that content type, I want only to list the members which have that specific location.

Right now I’ve tried to create the links and filter by that like so:
Normal Jobpage with all members is: www.mydomain.com/jobpage
Filtered Jobpage is: www.mydomain.com/jobpage/Dublin

I’m using Views for my Jobpage and is there any way to “filter” by creating a link URL structure as described and how do I set this up??

Any suggestion or help is very much appreciated.

Sincere
- Mestika

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an argument on your view to apply the filter from the URL. If you set the "action to take if argument is not present" to display all values then your standard job page will continue to function as before.

In Drupal 7 arguments are called "contextual filters" and are hidden amongst the "advanced" view options.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module called [Node Reference URL widget](http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_url) and it will allow views to take argument from URL and filter content according to that.